# Trouble passing parameter to child state in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states, one is a child of the other. One represents a list of people (`people`) and one for when you click on an individual person to view more details (`people.detail`).

My first state works as intended, and has several parameters which represent all the various server side filters and paging you could apply.  The child state is a modal window, which popups as expected but my only paramater `personID` never makes it into `$stateParams`.  I wonder if it's something to do the combination of the RESTful style URL and the query string style?

It is perhaps worth noting that `$stateParams` is populated with everything you'd expect from the parent state.

EDIT: Plunker to show what I mean - [http://plnkr.co/edit/eNMIEt?p=info](http://plnkr.co/edit/d4xWwYdPqbvuvqaypECL?p=preview) (note that the ID is undefined)

app.js

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/people');

    $stateProvider
        .state('people', {
            url: '/people?pageNumber&pageSize&sortField&sortDirection&search&countryID&jobFunctionIDs&firmTypeIDs',
            templateUrl: 'Static/js/angular/views/people-list.html',
            controller: 'PeopleListController',
            resolve: {
                api: "api",
                people: function (api, $stateParams) {
                    //Code ommitted
                },
                countries: function (api) {
                    //Code ommitted
                },
                jobFunctions: function (api) {
                   //Code ommitted
                },
                firmTypes: function (api) {
                    //Code ommitted
                }
            }

        });

    modalStateProvider.state('people.detail', {
        url: "/{personID}",
        templateUrl: 'Static/js/angular/views/people-detail.html',
        controller: function () {

        },
        resolve: {
            person: function (api, $stateParams) {
                return api.people.getDetail($stateParams.personID);
            }
        }
    });
```

The `modalStateProvider` looks like:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.provider('modalState', function ($stateProvider) {
    var provider = this;
    this.$get = function () {
        return provider;
    }
    this.state = function (stateName, options) {
        var modalInstance;
        $stateProvider.state(stateName, {
            url: options.url,
            onEnter: function ($modal, $state) {
                modalInstance = $modal.open(options);
                modalInstance.result['finally'](function () {
                    modalInstance = null;
                    if ($state.$current.name === stateName) {
                        $state.go('^');
                    }
                });
            },
            onExit: function () {
                if (modalInstance) {
                    modalInstance.close();
                }
            }
        });
    };
})
```

And finally my function in my controller to transition to the `people.detail` state:

```
    $scope.transitionToPersonDetail = function (personID) {
        $state.transitionTo('.detail', { personID: personID }, { location: true, inherit: true, relative: $state.$current, notify: false });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot more inspection I'm still not entirely sure why this was happening, I think it had something to do with the `modalStateProvider`'s scope with `$stateParams` and the fact that the state wasn't "ready".  All of this is purely speculation however.

I fixed it with this code:

```
    $stateProvider.state('people.detail', {
        url: '/{personID:int}',
        onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', 'api', function($stateParams, $state, $modal, api) {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'Static/js/angular/views/people-detail.html',
                controller: function(person) {
                    console.log(person);
                },
                resolve: {
                    person: function() {
                        return api.people.getDetail($stateParams.personID);
                    }
                }
            }).result['finally'](function(result) {
                $state.transitionTo('people');
            });
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember the value from 'resolve' is directly available in controller, although I think it's worth checking if controller for your child view is triggered at all

```
modalStateProvider.state('people.detail', {
    url: "/:personID",
    templateUrl: 'Static/js/angular/views/people-detail.html',
    controller: function () {
      console.log(person)
    },
    resolve: {
        person: function (api, $stateParams) {
            return api.people.getDetail($stateParams.personID);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The controller is definitely triggered.  If I remove that `api.people.getDetail($stateParams.personID)` call (which returns a 500 from my web service as the personID is undefined) and replace to return a literal then it's logged.  Shown here - http://i.imgur.com/pHwe0lo.png

Comment: `url: "/:personID",` have you tried the ui-router params pattern? ;)

Comment: That makes no difference unfortunately, the `':personID` syntax is interchangeable with the curly brace syntax according to the documentation - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: I've run out of ideas, without 'working' example I can't do much more

Comment: Created a plunker to show what I'm seeing, you should hopefully see that personID when in state `people.detail` is undefined - http://plnkr.co/edit/eNMIEt?p=info

Comment: Something else I've just noticed is that if I set my `resolve` to return `$stateParams` at the time of the `resolve` execution my parameter isn't there, but when I reach the controller it does...